# How to set a default return value of an arbitrary type?

Tags: typescript

Example:

```
function parseInt<TDefault>(nbr: string, defaultValue:TDefault = null):number|TDefault {
   return Math.random() || defaultValue
}
```

> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'TDefault'.
> 'TDefault' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'null'.(2322)

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQMwrgdgxgLglgewsADgQwE4GcCmBJCGAHgBUARHENMAGxgD4AKCAIwwC5gsYM4IBzADTAAJpWp0Aamhpgc7cuNoxgAXmARaNAJTtNAWxY4MAH0VVlwAN4AoYPYw4YYDMgCyaGAAsAdBjQQIgj6jNrAJiaiSlIycjYAvjZAA)

This errors because `null` isn't necessarily of type `TDefault`, which makes sense, but I don't want to make the types looser because then my return value will have to include `|null`, but if you supply a default, then it's guaranteed to never be `null`.

So how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use method overrides:

```
export function parseInt<TDefault>(nbr: string, defaultValue: TDefault): number | TDefault
export function parseInt(nbr: string): number | null
export function parseInt(nbr: string, defaultValue: any = null) {
   return Math.random() || defaultValue
}

const x = parseInt("5.0")
const y = parseInt("bacon", {wat:9})
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzAQygGdgBJFGAHgBUARYBfJAGxgD4AKFAIygC44RGFEwoA5gBo4AEwZNWANXzMkwAXTksYASgEokAW27AocAD5wNjLQChQkWIlQZsuAsTIUuvAUJHjdOH0jE3MglmY7cGh4ZHQsHDxCEnIYb35BYVFJGU1FZVUBfBQATzgAXnDmZm04AG8bOCaoYBgkKFwAWXwYAAsAOihi6QgDDlqzC1lrfJVgGwBfGxs0HCE4EAqkj1SOACIAVn6ABj3tFbX4Msr3FK897nxVlD2pOoB3Hr4ATgXtIA)